# Netbeans shortcut to minimise all functions?

Tags: php, netbeans, keyboard-shortcuts

I recently got into Netbeans. I used to code in Visual studio, so I'm trying to figure out what all the shortcuts are that I used to use in Visual Studio. CTRL-SHIFT-S, for one, is the same. But I don't (and can't find online) the shortcut keys to minimise all FUNCTION in the code.

E.g:

```
function bla() {
  print 'hello';
  print 'world';
}
```

will become:

```
function bla() {..}
```

(i.e. minimised)

Anyone know how to do that?

Comment: I hope I'm allowed to ask this in the comment, but why? I code in PHP using Netbeans? Isn't this like a gray area?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default is <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>. But you can adjust this in Tools -> Options -> Keymap.

Comment: This collapses everything. Not just functions. It also collapses classes, code blocks (if, while, etc) and even comments.
This means that if a function has 3 ifs, a couple of loops and 5 multiline comments, you'll have to click 11 times to expand the functions and the other 10 collapsed blocks inside it.

Answer (score 3):

> Collapse (hide) all code blocks   Ctrl + Shift + NumPad Minus     Cmd +
>   Shift + Minus Expand a Collapsed Block (expand-fold)  Ctrl + Plus     Cmd
>   + Plus Expand a Collapsed Block (expand-fold)     Ctrl + NumPad Plus
>   Expand a Collapsed Block (expand-fold)    Ctrl + Equals   Cmd + Equals
>   Expand all code blocks (expand-all-folds)     Ctrl + Shift + NumPad Plus
>      Expand all code blocks (expand-all-folds)  Ctrl + Shift + Plus     Cmd
>   + Shift + Plus Expand all code blocks (expand-all-folds)  Ctrl + Shift
>   + Equals  Cmd + Shift + Equals

-> http://wiki.netbeans.org/KeymapProfileFor60

Comment: Your answer does not contain what the OP is looking for. There is no shortcut for only collapsing function/methods, but only to collapse "all", which also folds small constructs and comments and destroys readability.